# How To Match the begining and the end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

How To Match the begining and the end of a string but ignore everything in between. I made it like this, but the result is always zero for everything.

`document.write( (str.match(/^["“”'’]$/g) || []).length );`

```
// expected results
str = "please \"don't\" talk"; // 2
str = "please don't talk"; // 0
str = "Thomas' car"; // 1
```

to macth all the qoutes like in my code `str.match(/["“”'’]/g)`
but giving `^` and `$` is always giving zero result

Comment: And what does it mean? You want to match a single quote character?

Comment: Please explain in details what exactly you want to capture. Even after your question update it's still not clear. Like: **why** do you put `^` and `$` there?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not a native english it's hard to explain that, so I included the expected result

Comment: It's still not clear. `/^["“”'’]$/g` returns you zero results because it means: a one character long string which consists of a single quote character from the given set.

Comment: to match the start and the end, but it doesn't work

Comment: Well, it does work: your string is longer than one character. `str = "'";` would work fine and match exactly what your regex is trying to capture. "to match the start and the end" --- what does it mean?

Comment: I believe you need [`\B["“”'’]|["“”'’]\B`](https://regex101.com/r/cQ9pU1/2).

Comment: thanks! I thought there was a shorthand for doing this without `or` by using `^` and `$`

Comment: @stribizhev I tried your online testing with `\W` and `\s` both wrong, i never thought about commas and periods, the right answer is `\B` superb!

Comment: @JigongBagong: I posted the comment as an answer with some explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
document.write( (str.match(/["“”'’]\s|\s["“”'’]/g) || []).length );
```

and you will get a count for every quote that has an adjacent space. It won't work for a quote at the end of the string. If you need that also, ask.

The | separates different searches in this case. So we are searching for a quote followed by a space or a space followed by a quote. If you explicitly want the \" to be counted then the expression would be a little more complex. I am assuming the \ is just escaping " in the string.

Comment: That's impressive: how do you know the question has something to do with spaces?

Comment: yes this is it, but I change the `\s` to `\W` thanks @Paul

Comment: fair enough if you want non-word rather than non-space. The \B option mentioned in the other answer will allow the quote to be at the beginning and end of the string as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
\B["“”'’]|["“”'’]\B
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cQ9pU1/2)

The [non-word boundary `\B`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) make sure the match only occurs at a position that is not word boundary position:

> `\B` matches at any position between two word characters as well as at any position between two non-word characters.

So, `\B["“”'’]` matches all substrings that are not preceded with a word (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) character, and `["“”'’]\B` matches the apostrophes that are not followed by a word character.